# How do I call the Display trait on its polymorphic types?

Tags: rust

I have:

```
use std::fmt;
struct TeamMember {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

struct Manager {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

impl fmt::Display for TeamMember {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result { 
         write!(f, "TeamMember; name => {}, age => {}", self.name, self.age)
      }
}

impl fmt::Display for Manager {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result { 
         write!(f, "Manager; name => {}, age => {}", self.name, self.age)
      }
}

trait Employee {}

impl fmt::Display for Employee {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result { 
         write!(f, "{}", *self)
      }
}

fn main() {
    let t = TeamMember { name: "abc".to_string(), age: 23 };
    let t2 = Manager { name: "xyz".to_string(), age: 18 };

    let mut v: Vec<&Employee> = Vec::new();
    v.push(&t);
    v.push(&t2);

    for it in &v {
        println!("i am a {}", *it);
    }
}
```

I want to polymorphically call the displays of the 2 concrete types that the vector of trait objects references. I get the following compile error:

```
<std macros>:2:21: 2:52 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Employee` [E0277]
<std macros>:2 $ dst . write_fmt ( format_args ! ( $ ( $ arg ) * ) ) )
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<std macros>:2:21: 2:52 note: in this expansion of format_args!
```

The vector iteration should call the `Display` function for the concrete types...

Answer (score 2):

This finally worked, thanks:

```
use std::fmt;

struct TeamMember {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}
struct Manager {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

impl fmt::Display for TeamMember {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "TeamMember!; name => {}, age => {}", self.name, self.age)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Manager {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Manager!; name => {}, age => {}", self.name, self.age)
    }
}

trait Employee: fmt::Display {}
impl Employee for TeamMember {}
impl Employee for Manager {}

fn main() {
    let t = TeamMember {
        name: "abc".to_string(),
        age: 23,
    };
    let t2 = Manager {
        name: "xyz".to_string(),
        age: 18,
    };

    let mut v: Vec<&Employee> = Vec::new();
    v.push(&t);
    v.push(&t2);

    for it in &v {
        println!("i am a {}", *it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```
write!(f, "{}", *self)
```

You assume the type of `*self` (ie. `Employee`) implements `Display`, which is not guaranteed by the type constraints. So you should do:

```
trait Employee: fmt::Display {}
```

which, as a side effect, allows you to remove your `impl fmt::Display for Employee`.

Comment: I tried what you said, namely removed the impl fmt::Display for Employee and extended Employee from fmt:Display but didn't work.

Comment: now i get => rustc /home/dastoor/rust_examples/polymorphic_display_trait.rs
/home/dastoor/rust_examples/polymorphic_display_trait.rs:40:12: 40:14 error: the trait `Employee` is not implemented for the type `TeamMember` [E0277]
/home/dastoor/rust_examples/polymorphic_display_trait.rs:40     v.push(&t);

Comment: Those are an other issue. And the error message is rather explicit about what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Employee` has no methods, there's no need to create another trait. You can just use `Display` directly:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    let t = TeamMember { name: "abc".to_string(), age: 23 };
    let t2 = Manager { name: "xyz".to_string(), age: 18 };

    let v = vec![&t as &Display, &t2];
    for it in &v {
        println!("i am a {}", *it);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to have an `Employee` trait that *didn't* require `Display` to be implemented (as is required in [Valentin Lorentz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37237967/155423)), you could create another trait that requires both:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

trait Employee {}
impl Employee for TeamMember {}
impl Employee for Manager {}

trait PrintableEmployee: Employee + Display {}
impl<T> PrintableEmployee for T where T: Employee + Display {}

fn main() {
    let t = TeamMember { name: "abc".to_string(), age: 23 };
    let t2 = Manager { name: "xyz".to_string(), age: 18 };

    let v = vec![&t as &PrintableEmployee, &t2];

    for it in &v {
        println!("i am a {}", *it);
    }
}
```

Comment: very interesting... thanks.. of course if Employee had other funcs in them, but i wanted to leverage the std::Display trait (without defining a new func in the trait to that effect), then i guess, that would be the way to go, right ?